# Solr multiple search and group by date range

Tags: time, lucene, solr, range, faceted-search

if have the problem to execute multiple Solr queries at ones with the same phrase but for different timeranges.
Example:

```
search for "atom" at:
2011-04-01T10:20:22.0Z TO 2011-04-01T12:20:22.0Z
2011-03-08T10:20:22.0Z TO 2011-03-08T12:20:22.0Z
2011-02-05T10:20:22.0Z TO 2011-02-05T12:20:22.0Z
```

So i need a few messages from each 2 hour interval.
First of all, i thought about facet search, but i don't think, thats a way, is'n it?

2nd idea was to fire one solr request for every time range. But probably there is to much (network)overhead for that, because this example is only an simplified version.

Maybe anybody has an idea, how could i handle this? What solr functionality is the best way for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FieldCollapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) with the group by query option.

Comment: oh yeah, very nice, new feature. thank you - that is what i was looking for!